# Is there any software to help with systems of differential equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, differential

I am wondering if anybody knows of a computer software that can help calculate equations like:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{d^2y}{dt} = e^{4t}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt} + x + \frac{dy}{dt} - y = 4e^{2t}$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why don't you use Laplace Transform ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differential+equation+solver, this should solve most of your problems.

Comment: This is a comment more than an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica or Maple are good proprietary software with free trials that can solve this.

Sympy and Sage are good open source solutions that can try to solve this. Sage is more like Mathematica or Maple, Sympy is raw python code.

Comment: This is a comment more than an answer...